# Blockchain.info not sending my IPN to my website

Tags: api, blockchain.info

Ok, so I have set up my blockchain.info API. But when I send a payment to the address given, it doesnt send the data. I use the exact same settings and callback in the testing, and it works amazingly. The thing is, blockchain.info doesn't even send my IPN. I know this because my first code is to insert a json format of all $_GET parameters into a database. Any fix?

Comment: Is blockchain not sending, or is your script not adding it to the database? You can figure out which is which by running tcpdump.

Comment: Blockchain is not sending. Any get parameter that reaches the callback url, is automatically added to a database named "test". So if i went and just put callback.php?g=fds, I would get the get parameter in json format in my database. But after 15 confirmations, still nothing

Comment: That doesn't eliminate, for example,  the possibility that a firewall blocked the callback.

Comment: But any attempt to visit the site is logged, and I get nothing :\